# Nginx Conf conflict www 502

Tags: nginx

my website work with hsts http redirection https working but when i want use www i have 502 nginx in brower

I have alias in panel [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

and my log error when i type nginx -t

nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "mydomain.com" on MYIP:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.mydomain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

**Nginx.conf**

```
server {

listen       80;

server_name  www.mydomain.com;


}

server {

listen      myIP:80;

server_name  mydomain.com;

root        /home/razor/web/mydomain.com/public_html;

index       index.php index.html index.htm;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/mydomain.com.log combined;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/mydomain.com.bytes bytes;

error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/mydomain.com.error.log error;

include /home/razor/conf/web/mydomain.com/nginx.forcessl.conf*;

location / {

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
        fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-mydomain.com.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/razor/web/mydomain.com/document_errors/;
}

location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    deny    all;
    return  404;
}

location /vstats/ {
    alias   /home/razor/web/mydomain.com/stats/;
    include /home/razor/web/mydomain.com/stats/auth.conf*;
}

include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
include     /home/razor/conf/web/mydomain.com/nginx.conf_*;
}
```

**nginx.hsts.conf**

```
client_max_body_size 5G;

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?_page_url=$1 last; }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm-php8.fhscript.com.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MOD_X_ACCEL_REDIRECT_ENABLED on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

 #location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?_page_url=$1 last;
    }
 #}

location /files/ {
    internal;
}

# these locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
location /logs/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NGINX processed the configuration file line by line or for the order of files in alphabetical order.

What is happening here is you have provided 2 blocks to NGINX that are listening on port 80.

Just **remove** this part and you should be good to go.

```
server {

listen       80;

server_name  www.mydomain.com;


}
```